# How can I assign a value to a Html.Hiddenfor from jQuery/ JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a hidden asp.net MVC control in the form:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NodeId) %>
```

**My JavaScript / jQuery code:**

```
var DeleteEntireItem = '<% = btnDeleteEntireMenu.ClientID%>';
var Node;
debugger;

$('#' + DeleteEntireItem).click(function () {
    Node = NodeValue;
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

How can I assign the value of variable 'Node' to the asp.net MVC hidden control?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the value attribute of a hidden input tag by selecting it using the property name and using the jquery val() method.

In your case this becomes:

```
$("#NodeId").val(Node)
```